# Pyramid: generate json views from list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pyramid

How to generate `json` views from a list of strings with Pyramid?

With the following attempt only the view of the last element of the list is generated; `jkl_json` in this case,  the others produce `404 Not Found`.

```
names = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
for nm in names:
    @view_config(route_name='{}_json'.format(nm),
                 renderer='json',)
    def names_json(request):
        nm_cls = globals()[nm.title()]
        ...
```

This does actually work with html views; but not with json views.

Comment: You need both `@view_config` and `add_route` unless you use something like `@simple_route` that does both route and view configuration: http://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.core.route.html?highlight=simple_route#websauna.system.core.route.simple_route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Pyramid uses the Venusian library for decorators; they attach information to functions instead of registering the view instantly. This information is later processed by `config.scan`, and only then is the route actually registered. In your code you're replacing the `names_json` function with *another* function by the same name on each loop. Since only last of them is visible in the module, with only the last `view_config` data attached to it, this is what Venusian picks up when scanning.

---

You should instead apply the decorators to exactly one function. If you remember that

```
 @view_config(route_name='foo')
 def bar(request):
     return Response()
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
 def bar(request):
     return Response()

 bar = view_config(route_name='foo')
```

you can do

```
def names_json(request):
    ...

names = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
for nm in names:
    names_json = view_config(route_name='{}_json'.format(nm),
             renderer='json')(names_json)
```

---

On the other hand, if the paths are like this, perhaps you can just use a single route for all of them:

```
config.add_route('names', '/foo/{name:abc|def|ghi|jkl}.json')
```

where the route would match any of `/foo/abc.json`, `/foo/def.json`, `/foo/ghi.json` or `/foo/jkl.json`, and the name would be available as `request.matchdict['name']` within the view.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the [Configurator.add_view](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_view) method to add views programmatically:

```
def json_view(request):
    ...

names = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
for nm in names:
    config.add_view(json_view, route_name='{}_json'.format(nm),
                 renderer='json',)
```

Your approach with decorators in a loop is unlikely to work even with html I think...

Comment: I get AttributeError: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'maybe_dotted'` in `application\lib\site-packages\pyramid\util.py", line 519`. How do you import `config`?